# Custom onClick attribute is not working

Tags: android, onclick, android-custom-view

I created a compound view consisting of one `TextView` and one "Buy" `Button`.

For my compound view, I made a custom attribute called `onBuyClick`. It is supposed to serve the same purpose as the `View`'s `onClick` attribute, but have the listener not on the whole view but only on the button. So, the first thing I did is copy from the `View` class what the `onClick` attribute does. And it worked! (with minor adaptations).

But as soon as I add `btnBuy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {`, it becomes unable to find the method I want it to get and throws `IllegalStateException` (**The second one, where `NoSuchMethodException` is being caught**).

Here is the piece that executed once the is an `onBuyClick` attribute:

```
if (context.isRestricted()) {
    throw new IllegalStateException("The android:onClick attribute cannot "
            + "be used within a restricted context");
}

final String handlerName = a.getString(attr);
if (handlerName != null) {
    btnBuy.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() { //As soon as "btnBuy." is added, everything crashes once the button is pressed.
        private Method mHandler;

        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (mHandler == null) {
                try {
                    mHandler = getContext().getClass().getMethod(handlerName,
                            View.class);
                } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
                    int id = getId();
                    String idText = id == NO_ID ? "" : " with id '"
                            + getContext().getResources().getResourceEntryName(
                            id) + "'";
                    throw new IllegalStateException("Could not find a method " +
                            handlerName + "(View) in the activity "
                            + getContext().getClass() + " for onClick handler"
                            + " on view " + this.getClass() + idText, e);
                }
            }

            try {
                mHandler.invoke(getContext(), this);
            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Could not execute non "
                        + "public method of the activity", e);
            } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
                throw new IllegalStateException("Could not execute "
                        + "method of the activity", e);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

and here are the variables defined outside this piece: `btnBuy`, the "Buy" `Button` in my compound view, and `a` is a `TypedArray` containing all my attributes.

Can someone please help me?

Comment: For the starter, which `IllegalStateException` is thrown? There are 4 of them on the code.

Comment: can you pot the entire class